# Iterate all app_code types in a .Net Website project C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

From a code behind (I know..) I'm trying to create a list of types that implement a specific interface.  The types are within the website projects app_code folder.

Website projects dynamically compile into multiple assemblies, this means that for example `Assembly.GetCurrentlyExecutingAssembly()` and similar calls e.g.`GetType().Assembly` don't contain the types I'm looking for.  Apart from the walnut with a sledgehammer approach of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() is there some way of iterating only the types defined within the website project?

Of course I could move all this functionality into a separate project where it behaves more predictably, but that is a refactor too far at the moment.

Comment: I don't think you have much choice other than to iterate over all assemblies.

Comment: All the classes under the app_code folder will be compiled into the same assembly. Why don't you just use the following: `typeof(SOME_KNOWN_TYPE_FROM_APP_CODE).Assembly` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a code-behind file, you should be able to execute the following line of code to enumerate only the types compiled from the classes under the app_code folder.

Assuming that `IViusalizationManager` is one of the classes under the app_code folder:

```
Type[] app_codeTypeList = typeof(IViusalizationManager).Assembly.GetTypes();
```

Comment: Aren't code-behind files compiled at build time? Whereas app_code is compiled later? If so, how are you even going to reference the assembly containing `IVisualizationManager` (or any other type)?

Comment: This is a "Web Site" project, not a "Web Application" project. For web site projects, what builds when depends on the deployment strategy of your choice. If you compile nothing and just copy all the app_code/*.cs, aspx, aspx.cs ascx etc. files onto your server, app_code (and global.asax) will be complied with the first request, and, requested pages and dependent controls will also be compiled when demanded for the first time.

Comment: You can select to publish your web site, and in that case the pages, controls (ascx files) as well as app_code, global.asax, etc. will be pre-compiled (depending on your pre-compilation choices), but still, what the OP wants is to test the types compiled from app_code for whether they implement a specific interface or not, therefore, he can get the assembly as such.

Comment: This worked fine in local debug mode, which is not fully pre-compiled as it can be with publishing, in any case when I made this change and refreshed the page triggering a dynamic re-compile it still had no trouble finding the types I was looking for under app_code.